# Can I pin recipes to specific versions in an environment?

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I know recipes aren't versioned, but is it possible in an environment to have some recipes use a specific version of their cookbook and some use a different version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only pin cookbooks in environments. There is no way to mix a cookbook with recipes from different cookbook versions.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.

Cookbooks are the unit of versioning, there's no way to pin recipes.

You can copy either the old or the new cookbook to a new name (`cookbook_v1` or `cookbook_ng`) or you can include two different versions of the recipe in the new cookbook (`recipes/stuff_v1.rb` `recipes/stuff_v2.rb`) but you can't do what you're asking.